# How to measure / calculate Tait-Bryan angles of a moving platform in SimMechanics

Tags: mechanical-engineering, simulation, solidworks, kinematics, simulink

I exported a model of the mechanism created in SolidWorks to SimMechanics in order to explore the possibilities of control. To solve the problem, i need to know the angular position of the mobile platform. In reality, I can do this with the help of a sensor.

How to calculate these angles in SimMechanics?

[image: Structure]

[image: Mechanism]